# Reporting from SQL Azure - What do I use now?

Tags: azure, reporting, .net-core

Back in the day Visual Basic came with Crystal Reports and it was (relatively) easy. Then we all moved on to SSRS and the wonders of .rdlc files. 
Nowadays it's all about the cloud and I've just about got over the news I can't do that any more because SQL in Azure doesn't support it. What I have not been able to find out yet is what I do instead. 
I need 'real-time' reporting on my live data as it is in the database. Ideally I'd like to use a nice GUI to design my reports like I always have with Crystal and with SSRS. I'd like to be able to output in PDF and Excel formats and because I'm trying to live on the bleeding edge I'm coding in .Net Core.

So my question is what I should be using now? Am I using supposed to be using PowerBI then, or is there some other option please? I've considered KendoUI and jsPDF but I'm not keen to go at it from the code side of things unless I have to.

Apologies in advance if I just haven't typed the right thing into Google to find this, I promise I did try. Thanks in advance for setting me straight!

Answer (score 1):

I think Power BI or Power BI Embedded would be the ticket- perhaps using DirectQuery mode so you get a live picture of the data.

If you're building a business-to-business application and you want to embed reporting in it,  Microsoft would (currently) suggest you use Power BI Embedded. You could of course use one of many other reporting APIs that fit in with your application's toolset. The pricing model for Power BI Embedded is essentially per render (although it is slightly more complicated than that).

If your reporting is all internal, you could use Power BI ('Power BI Service') which comes with its own portal, or you can embed it in your appications (as long as your users have Power BI licenses).

You could still use SSRS to connect to an Azure SQL database, but you need somewhere for SSRS to run from, either on premises or as an IaaS VM in Azure.

Comment: Just to address a couple of the points above:
It's a SaaS product so there will be lots of users, it's not just in-house. 
I'm perfectly happy with PowerBI if that's the answer although I think it upsets me a little having to pay per render - we can price it accordingly, but in the old days we had a VM with SQL Server on and we ran as many PDFs out as we wanted without having to worry about it.

We never really used SSRS on the server, it was a case of LocalReport and dynamically return a datatable in code and set that as the ReportSource, then call the Render method

Comment: Fair enough, Power BI Embedded would be the Power BI option for you (right now- it might change in future). It is expensive- google for embedded BI and reporting and you'll find many paid for products aimed at this use case, and plenty free. You could very happily have a VM on Azure that used Localreports to put out PDFs. It would be cheap, because it wouldn't need to be a large size. You wouldn't need SQL Server on it at all. But I'm sure an embedded BI API would do that job too.